# AppEngineLauncher no longer shows status icons?

Tags: python, macos, google-app-engine, python-2.7

The latest version of appengine launcher for mac does not show status icons. What's the best way to report this? I'm on the latest Mac OS 10.9.2

[image: screenshot of appenginelauncher]

Comment: The icons above Edit, Deploy, and Dashboard are also missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit this bug via the ["defect" formular](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry?template=Defect).